# laravel / lumen access .env values in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Is there any way to access .env vals from inside of a middleware script?

I have tried to do so by env('KEY') but this seems to return null most of the time.

Does any one know of a better way to do this inside of middleware or a way to insure the .env file has been loaded before the middleware runs?

Comment: Mine works well. How do you call `env` in your middleware? Have you set `env` file correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `config()` to access `.env` variables. For example, if you want to get MySQL port, use this:

```
$mysqlPort = config()['database']['connections']['mysql']['port'];
```

To get all available variables, you can do `dd(config());`

If you want to use custom variables in `.env`, you also can do this:

```
CUSTOM=hello
```

And to get this variable, use `env()` helper:

```
echo env('CUSTOM'); // Will output 'hello'
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey but this actually does not work. Whats returned does not contain any of my custom variables.

Comment: Do you want to put custom var in `.env` and then get it in your app code? Please look at updated answer.

Comment: Yes and this works but not inside of middleware. About 90% of the time it will be null form inside of middleware.

Comment: is there something similar to app()->environment() to pull other .env values?

Comment: Does `getenv('CUSTOM')` work in middleware? Also, maybe creating custom config file in `config` direcotry and using it is an option?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the issue i was having was from also trying to get the APP_KEY. It looks like all is working with both getenv() and just env() as long as I get retrieve just custom vars. Not sure why it did not work when i first removed the env(APP_KEY) but its working now. Maybe lumen had something cached.